# Training the unskilled

Tags: education

Are there any studies on programs/policies (anywhere on the world) that try to address the problem of missing life-long education? Some possible approaches to analyze:

- Making attending training mandatory for the unemployed (rather than fruitlessly looking for a job).
- Targeted programs to help professionals in dying industries to re-train into new areas. (ex. SAP courses for paper-based accountants/secretaries)
- Financial schemes to support training. (ex. university subsidies)
- ...

Especially to combat unemployment - is it not better to invest in some education before attempting to bring the unskilled/unemployed into the job market. Fundamentally for example, to teach B1 lvl of language competence before requiring someone to look for a job. (It's practically impossible to find a satisfying job without knowing the language.)

Comment: In germany long-term unemployed are excluded from the minimum wage for a few months, so that it is easier for them to find a job again

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of programs based on similar ideas and, although, I am not very familiar with it, I am sure there is a lot of research on their effectiveness. But the assumption implicit in your question that unemployment (long-term or not) results from a lack of life-long education that is itself largely voluntary is patronizing and unrealistic.

Also, the people furthest from the regular job market often have to deal with many other issues (ranging from no car/limited mobility, children to take care of – Germany has long been particularly bad in this respect, patchy work history, lack of basic reading or computer skills and difficulties with the local language to lack of basic discipline, addictions, disabilities, psychiatric issues, abusive relationships, etc.) so simply forcing everybody who is unemployed into some sit-down training is unlikely to achieve anything.

Many (intelligent and able) people also have difficulties with the sort of arbitrary discipline and abstract thinking our education system demands to begin with. Often, they disliked school and end up among the least employable precisely because they didn't get any advanced diploma. Bringing them back in the type of school-like environment implied by your suggestions does not sound like a particularly promising idea.

Just to give you an example of what I mean here, I can describe one specific approach I am a little familiar with. In France, there are a number of structures (called “atelier chantier d'insertion”) where long-term unemployed people selected by the national job agency get a one or two-year contract doing things like ironing or growing vegetables (the products/services are sold on the market but the activity would not be profitable without subsidies). For the workers, it means a better income and the possibility to plan ahead a little, an opportunity to show they can hold a job and to (re)learn many basic skills (from coming on time to using a computer) and possibly some more specific marketable skills like working in a retail shop, without being in a school-like environment. The staff typically includes a social worker that should help them prepare a project for the time after the temporary contract.

That's but one specific example but this type of things (and also all sorts of more traditional training) are widespread. But the simple truth is that economic growth makes a huge difference. When the economy is not doing well, qualified applicants are forced to consider entry-level jobs, employers can be picky and less qualified applicants get pushed out. Even the best training won't make someone more attractive than another candidate who just left the exact same job elsewhere.

The fact that periods of high unemployment have long-lasting effects is also well documented. People often slide into long-term unemployment and thus become less and less employable because the less attractive/less stable entry-level jobs they could usually pretend to get filled with other applicants. After struggling to find a job for years, many will understandably retract from the job market entirely and stop being counted as unemployed, sometimes turning to disability payments or other sources of income when available.

In the meantime, at the other end of the job market, employers complain about the lack of skilled workers but that's mostly because they want *cheap* qualified employees that are immediately effective with the technology *du jour*, without any effort to recruit or train other potentially qualified applicants. For if there was a genuine shortage of skilled work, in a market-based economy, the logical consequences would be a general wage increase but that has not been happening.

Those (and the catastrophic macroeconomic policies in the EU/Eurozone) are the issues we are dealing with. All the talk about a purported “skill gap” and “training” as a cure for unemployment has been going on for decades but it's a cop out, a way to keep talking about some relatively painless solution (who can oppose education?) without confronting difficult problems.

Incidentally, in Western European countries, there are also opportunities for people who do not speak the language well, some employers even cynically prefer such employees (say for fruit picking, hotel cleaning, etc.) so while learning the local language can benefit anyone, that's not an explanation for long-term unemployment either.

Comment: Very good point about leaving the job market.  I think I just heard a report on the news where they reported that US jobs grew, but unemployment stayed flat because people who had previously left the market were re-entering it and now *they* were looking for jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer, and I apologize for coming across in a condescending way, that wasn't my intention. I was writing from my own limited experience, and I am aware that the education system has flaws. I was hoping for some references to success stories - perhaps what you mentioned about the "atelier chantier d'insertion" in france.

Comment: *sigh*. The surest sign that civilization has reached its peak and is doomed is the fact that fully serious people un-ironically consider "coming on time" as a special skill, as opposed to basic requirement to avoid dying that everyone 8 years old and on was fully equipped with since humans learned agriculture. Being late used to be a privilege of useless idle rich nobles.

Comment: @user4012 Call it what you want, this is not the point. And incidentally, your comment is complete BS, caring about time in that way is highly culturally determined and by no means something people took for granted until very recently.

Comment: @Relaxed - I take it you never looked into how farmers (especially those with lifestock) lived? Cows really could care less about sociological theories blaming laziness and lack of work ethic afforded by 20th century social safety nets on "culture". You don't plant/milk on time, you don't eat. It's that simple.

Comment: @user4012 Oh, but I did, and that's how I know for a fact you have no idea what you are talking about. There is a huge difference between meeting some arbitrary clock and planting on time. For a long time, people did not work nearly as much as you might suspect (that's true for hunter gatherers but also for much of agricultural people, certainly in Europe, up to the Middle Ages) and even as work took more and more time, in the 19th century, it would usually be through the pressure to produce more, but at home, at your own pace, with no clear notion of being on or off-work.

Comment: And still today, different countries/cultures have different attitudes with respect to time and time-keeping in a way that's completely unrelated to “work ethics” or the like.

Comment: @Relaxed - the clock is absolutely NOT arbitrary. It's defined by available sunlight for plant growing and by animal biorhythms for animal raising. (hunter-gatherers are a wholly different ballgame, they weren't as tied to precise timing as agricultural society).

Comment: @user4012 The point is that in some cultures, you are expected to be on time *to the minute* in others not so much. Until the 19th Century, you would not *go to work* and nobody would track time in that way. That's the part that's new and arbitrary. Of course, seasons or livestock were important but that's something else entirely. And this sort of precise timekeeping also exists in countries where people are not working all that much (say in Germany or the Netherlands today).

Comment: By contrast, there are countries where people work long hours and have absolutely no expectation to be free by 5 pm, yet don't care about a 5-10 min delay or really have any precise schedule at all.

Comment: @Relaxed - your father typically tracked if you were late to do your chores. "To the minute" precision is a function of economic requirements (everyone in the factory has to start same time); but the concept of getting up with sunrize isn't exactly an invention of 19th century and their precise time-keeping clocks.

Comment: @user4012 Well, this precision is exactly what my example was about, not agriculture, so you now see why your comment was irrelevant. And you have no idea what my father did. You really seem to take some characteristics of mid-century American society for granted but the world is wider than that.

Comment: @Relaxed - since my notion of farming doesn't come from America, your model of why I have information I do seems... somewhat not based on reality.

Comment: @user4012 I was talking about your reference to the role of fathers and generally your relationship to time, not about farming since I already explained at length why that's mostly unrelated to the point I was making. There are few other countries which are similar in those respects (I already mentioned some) but not many. The fact that you didn't simply state you were not from the US but had to invoke some unspecified experience of farming somewhere else kind of confirms my hunch, incidentally.